# Behavior of infinite limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = C$, where $0 < C < \infty$. Can I conclude
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)g(x) = +\infty?$$
This seems true due the following heuristic argument: for any $M > 0$, we can choose $x$ very close to 0 such that $f(x) > M$ and $g(x)$ close to $C$. But then $f(x)g(x) >\sim CM$.

Comment: If $f$ goes to infinity, then $\epsilon f(x)$ for all fixed $\epsilon >0$ also goes to infinity. Now let $\epsilon$ be a positive lower bound for $g$ in some neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is right:

Let $m>0$ be given.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty$, there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that $\displaystyle 0<x<\delta_1\implies f(x)>\frac{2m}{C}$.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=C$, there is a $\delta_2>0$ such that $\displaystyle 0<x<\delta_2\implies |g(x)-C|<\frac{C}{2}$.

If $\displaystyle\delta=\min(\delta_1, \delta_2),$ then $\displaystyle 0<x<\delta\implies f(x)g(x)>\left(\frac{2m}{C}\right)\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=m$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true : suppose $f,g\geq 0$ (to avoid absolute value that i dont know how to write with a mac :o)

let $\epsilon>0$ very big. There exists $\alpha,\beta>0$ very small (close to $0$) such that for all $x<\alpha$, we have $f(x)> \epsilon$ and for all $x<\beta$ we have$C-\frac{1}{\epsilon} < g(x) < C+\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.
Hence, for $x<\min(\alpha,\beta)$, we get  $f(x)g(x)> \epsilon C -1$.